# Point as an element of an affine space vs point as an element of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, elementary-set-theory, definition, computational-geometry

I am searching for the "most natural" definition of a (geometrical/space) point as an element of "something" in mathematics (I am trying to design a small computational geometry library on strong mathematical basis). For example, for a vector, it's easy: a vector is an element of a vector space, end of story. Same for a tensor: a tensor is an element of the tensor product of vector spaces. But how to define a point in the same way?

1. Can a point be defined as an element of an affine space or as an element of a topological space?
2. If both are true, what are the difference between the two types of points, and what would be the most natural (it's subjective) approach to define a point in geometry?
3. Moreover, do other approaches exist (a point is an element of XXXX)?

EDIT: I know that a point is an axiom/primitive notion but to design the library I need to make a choice. And I want to know the best option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point is a primitive notion. In particular, a primitive notion is not defined in terms of previously defined concepts, but is only motivated informally, usually by an appeal to intuition and everyday experience. A vector or a tensor is not an undefined notion, in fact their existence relies on the existence (the definition) of a vector space (tensor product space). If you cancel the concept of vector space, what is a vector? But even if you forgot all the mathematic knowledge, you know what a point is. The only reason is that the "definition" of a point (better say: the concept of a point) doesn't lie in mathematics.

If you define a point as an element of a set X, you are not define a "point" but you call the elements of such set X "points".

In fact defining a "point" as an element of a set $X$ automatically bring some extra property to the "point". Properties which are related to the starting set $X$ **and so they don't hold in general**.

An example: if you define a "point" as an element of an affine space you automatically have the property of subtracting one point from another to gain a vector (a "point" of a vector space which has other properties in relation to other "points" of the same set). Such property is impossible to have if you define "point" as elements of topological spaces. **assuming I understand what you mean** the only criterion valid for defining "points" in this way is "what property" I want attached to them?

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: Mmh but I don't see how you can define a point as an element of something. No problem if you think I've missed the point :)

Comment: @Vincent According to me is like to trying to define a set as an element of the power set of something. It neither create order nor explain the notation better

Comment: From the programming point of view, to declare an element (for runtime execution) one of the best option is to define the set it comes from at compile-time: when you declare a vector you can say "I take an element of this vector space". If you have the knowledge on affine space/topological space, could you elaborate on question 1./2. so I can upvote your explanation ?

Comment: @Vincent tried to elaborate further my opinion :)

Comment: Thanks. Last question if you have time: what are the extra properties I bring to point if I define them as members of a topological space (in the most general sense).

Comment: @Vincent I thought about it, I think it relies heavily on the topology which we are working with. (The basic operations in this case are union and intersection according to me)

Answer (score 1):

A "space" in mathematics in its most primitive form consists of an underlying set, and elements of this set are usually referred to as "points". But what makes a set an actual "space" is some sort of additional structure imposed on the underlying set, the most simple geometric structure being a topology on the set.